# How to calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(cx)}{x}dx$?

Tags: calculus

Let $c$ be a real number. How to calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(cx)}{x}dx$? By using Mathematica, I know the final answer is
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\text{sign}(c),$$
where $\text{sign}(c)$ gives $-1$, $0$, or $1$ depending on whether $c$ is negative, zero, or positive. But I don't know how to calculate the answer. Any comments or solutions are welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: Substitute $u = \lvert c\rvert\cdot x$.

Comment: do you know that $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ or do you have to proove that as well?

Comment: To Daniel: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: To Borge: Yes, I know $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $cx=u$ and $c>0$*, the integral becomes

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(cx)}x\,dx=\int_{0/c}^{\infty/c} \frac{\sin(u)}{cu}\,c\,du=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(u)}{u}du=I,$$ which is a constant (if it exists).

When $c=0$ or $c<0$ you just get $0$ or $-I$, as the sine function is odd.

*The condition on the sign of $c$ is required to let the upper bound remain $\infty$.

---

You cannot compute the exact value of $I$ by elementary means, as the indefinite integral has no closed form.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu. You should tick the question when satisfied.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, why does Wolfram give a neat answer? $\frac\pi2$?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I took the care to add a link, please read it.

Comment: Ohh Sorry! My bad. (y)

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal OK, I will tick the question when satisfied.